# Python requests library usage inside class initialization usage confusion

Tags: python, class, python-requests

First and foremost let me apologize for the perhaps horrendous question title, but it is late and searching hasn't yielded any results on how to phrase this more aptly.

I have stumbled upon this interesting code today which basically downloads udemy videos for you (can be found here: https://github.com/gaganpreet/udemy-dl/blob/master/udemy-dl.py)
The code is more or less clear to me in terms of program flow but what i do not understand is what exactly is happening inside the class initiator on line 20/21 and how this is vital for the code to function.

I would appreciate a helpful nudge in the right direction because i do not understand what "requests.Session()" does at all, it looks to me like the instance of that class when it is created has a self.session value assigned to requests.Session(), but isnt Session() a class constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `requests.Session()` is a call to a constructor.

There is a `Session` class defined in the `requests` library which is independent of the `Session` class that is defined in the code you linked, and it is the `requests` version of `Session` which is being constructed in the constructor on line 20-21.

This is understandably confusing because there is a name reuse between the code and the library it is invoking, which is resolved by the prefix `requests`.

As Huu Ngyuyen's comment below mentions, the documentation on [namespaces](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) should help you better understand what is happening.

Comment: The official tutorial [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) on `namespaces` should also help.

Comment: Thank you @HuuNguyen and merlin2011 for your quick and concise replies. Consider this matter resolved. Time to do some reading :)